# private variable is still accessible from another class in C#

Tags: class, variables, set, private

I have a .cs file which looks like the following

```
namespace TarkovMapper.ClassObjects
{
    class PointCloud_Object
    {
        public void AddPoint(PointEntry_Object point)
        {
            PointLayer pointLayer = LoadPointLayer(path);
            pointLayer.Points[point.Location_x,point.Location_y]++;
        }
        private PointLayer LoadPointLayer(string path)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path)) return new PointLayer(this.Width, this.Height);
            Stream s = File.OpenRead(path);
            BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
            PointLayer returnObject = (PointLayer) b.Deserialize(s);
            s.Close();
            return returnObject;
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    class PointLayer
    {
        public PointLayer(int width, int height)
        {
            this.Points = new int[width, height];
        }
        public int[,] Points { get; private set; } // <- private set!!!
        public int Maximum { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

My Question is regarding the Variable "Points" in the class PointLayer.
Eventhough I have the Modifier `private set;` the following line in PointCloudObject is no issue `pointLayer.Points[point.Location_x,point.Location_y]++;`.

why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modifier refers to the Points array, not the array's individual elements.
The PointCloud_Object class cannot assign a new array to the PointLayer.Points variable, but it can manipulate the individual array elements.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Is there a way I can protect the elements inside the Array so they cant be modified from outside the Class?

Comment: I don't think you can protect the elements directly as long as the array is exposed.  One option would be to make the array private and provide a method that returns the individual elements.  Another option might be to use an alternate data structure instead of an array (maybe ReadOnlyCollection would meet your needs).